# MKV video files stutters GALAXY TAB 4 SM-T351

Tags: video, troubleshooting, benchmarks

So here we are, I have that big ass 10.1 inches screen and with the course of the years I have more and more troubles with playing the videos, especially the ones from Shaanig and MINX torrent releases.

I inspected my tab with Antutu and it shows me clearly that I have a really old device.

Surprisingly it is still possible to have a very smooth playback with Xtreme player, available in Play Market but this fact ignites my interest even more.

Why is it just about a one single player app that can run .mkv releases on my  device?

Is my device too old and there is no hope anymore for playing latest releases of all those .mkv-s?

Should I try another video players instead?

Here goes the Antutu results screenshots.
Antutu version - 9.1.7
I know that Antutu of 4.x.x. shows even worse results for my device something about 12.000

[image: Antutu 9.1.7 Screenshot]

[image: Antutu 9.1.7 Screenshot]

Comment: MKV is just a container, more relevant is what video type is inside. E.g. an MPEG4 or H265 video and the used encoding profile. If the video type and encoding profile is not supported by the hardware encoder of your tablet, then a stuttering playback is the common effect as everything has to be decoded by the CPU.

Comment: Some 3rd-party apps may include/provide their own codec pack to support more audio & video formats.

Comment: @Robert great answer actually that explains a lot. Would be just some awesome if you could share a link on a few articles about hardware encoders since I'm really dedicated to get to the bottom of this very interesting particular problem.

Comment: @AndrewT. Actually that was my very first thought I had. I explored the Play Market installing page and I lured anywhere that could give me a slighted hint on why Extreme Player does better job than the other but there was nothing. 
Also, VLC player is very famous for having his very own standalone codec pack but in this case it is not doing the job with MINX or SHAANIG releases any better than any other player.

Answer (score 0):

MKV is just a container (like AVI), more relevant is what video type is inside. E.g. an MPEG4 or H265 video and the used encoding profile. If the video type and encoding profile is not supported by the hardware encoder of your tablet, then a stuttering playback is the common effect as everything has to be decoded by the CPU. Additionally battery usage of software based decoding is way higher than decoding a video in hardware.

There are apps displaying all the codec available on your device, usually this means that a supported codec is decoded in hardware or at least mainly in hardware.

My preferred player is [MX Player](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mxtech.videoplayer.ad) (I prefer the ad free pro version). While the video is playing you can see which video decoder is used: SW (software), HW (hardware) or HW+ (hybrid of hardware accelerated decoding plus software enhancement).

If you have videos that can only be decoded in software I strongly recommend to reencode them on a PC using video transcoder like [Handbrake](https://handbrake.fr/) (or if you prefer to make it manually you can use ffmpeg).
If the PC has a GPU with integrated video encoding then reencoding does not take too much time.